# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier not picking up a loadNibNamed cell

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uitableview

I have a simple cell - designed in IB - and with the reuseIdentifier set. Below code works quite nicely. HOWever - the NSLog() reveals that the results are never cached.

Table view controller class:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
          cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
    switch/case for various cell types
    {
      Foo * item = [results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      return [MyCell tableView:tableView populatedCellWith:item];
    }
 }
```

MyCell class..

```
+(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView populatedCellWith:(Foo *)item  
{
   static NSString * identifier = @"XXX";

   MyCell *cell = (MyCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
       NSArray * items = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" 
                                 owner:self options:nil];
       cell = [items objectAtIndex:0];

       assert( cell && [cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:identifier]);

       NSLog(@"That was a load - rather than a nice cache for %@", self.class);
   }
   fill out some stuff.
   return cell;
```

}

Why is this - as it makes things a lot more efficient ?

Thanks,

Dw.

Comment: So you are seeing the NSLog more than once?  Just trying to clarify your question.

Comment: Yes indeed - and they have been set up with a cell identifier (whcih is what the 'assert' checks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you create the table view cell can not make sure to put the cell into the reusable queue in table view. Only way to do that is to use

```
initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:

Initializes a table cell with a style and a reuse identifier and returns it to the caller.
```

My another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945010/about-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the cells have been set with a cell identifier? `UITableView` will not cache those without.

Comment: It must be set in the xib, otherwise the `assert` would fail?

Comment: Correct - that is what the assert indeed confirms as set. Doing something silly (like assume a pointer compare) and chainging ot to pick up that identifier pointer rather than string value next time (e.g. with a identifier = cell.reuseIndentifier) does not help.

Comment: Whoops, I had missed the `assert` line, sorry. `UITV` can choose not to cache for a variety of reasons, but usually they boil down to missing reuse identifier or simply not having enough cells around (ie not enough rows to need caching). If neither applies, I'm at a loss.

Comment: Ok - the assert confirms that the reuseIndentifier is properly set. And it is not caching even when in the 40+ rows.