# About dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

Tags: uitableview, ios4

Case 1: create UITableViewCell with

```
initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:
```

Case 2: create UITableViewCell with

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" 
                             owner:self options:nil];
```

Case 1 will create reusable cell combined together with specific identifier,which will be pushed into the reusable queue.

Case 2 will create one cell from nib file, but can not be put into the reusable queue as case 1.

Question is

**any solution for case 2 to make the cell be reusable ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the XIB there is a setting for the UITableViewCell to set its reuse identifier. If you set it there, you can retrieve it as normal from the dequeue method.